# SDK does any API level. component have to be installed?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, installation, components

I changed my laptop so I have to install eclipse and android sdk again. I dont remember which component of every API level I should install.
I mean: I install Documentation for Android SDK, SDK platform, ARM eabi V7A System Image; Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Sources for Android SDK for the API level 21.

Should I install other components?

otherwise, if I want to install other APl levels, should I repeat the installation of the same components such like ARM EABI v7a System Image?

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Those system images are emulators. If you have a physical device use it, performance will be better and things like Google Maps don't really work on emulator as far as I recall.

You'll need to install only the API level you are developing the application against plus the following:
- Android SDK Tools
- Android SDK Platform Tools
- Android SDK Build-Tools
- Android Support Repository
- Android Support Library
- Google Play Services
- Google Repository
- Intel X86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer). Only if you want to use x86 emulators and after downloading this you'll still have to manually install from Extras folder.

You might not need all of them depending on what your application does but they should cover most cases.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
If I install only API level 21 (android 5.0) does the app run on devices with different version of android?

Comment: It can work, depends what APIs you are using and how build.gradle file is configured. Minimum version of the device that's going to run your app is set with "minSdkVersion", see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Basic-Build-Customization